# WPF pop up window disappears from UI unexpectedly

Tags: wpf, popup, showdialog

I have a modal pop up window in my wpf application. After showing that window, in some (rare) situations the window disappeared from the UI. But we can find that using “alt + tab” and can’t make it active.

Please find below the code i used,

```
       //WindowInteropHelper assists interoperation between Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) and Win32 code.

        private void OnControlClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        System.Drawing.Point p = System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition;
        MyPopup popup = new MyPopup();

        _windowInteropHelper = new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(popup);
        _windowInteropHelper.Owner = this._owner;
        popup.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
        popup.Left = p.X;
        popup.Top = p.Y;

        popup.Closing += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(OnPopupClosing);
        popup.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Comment: We probably need more code to understand what is happening. How is `_owner` getting its value? How is `MyPopup` defined? Is it possible to use the WPF `Popup` control instead?

Comment: MyPopup is derived from Window class and WindowInteropHelper class has a property called "Owner" of type IntPtr, which Gets or sets the handle of the WPF owner window. I need a modal window as a popup.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the IsOpen property to show/hide the popup.